# Update asp.net mvc project from Oauth to Oauth2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api, dotnetopenauth

I have a relatively old Asp.net mvc web project (created around 2012) which used Facebook connect using the AuthConfig.cs file and registered a client as so.

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
            appId: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookOAuthAppID"],
            appSecret: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookOAuthAppSecret"]
            );
```

Up until a few days ago when Facebook changed to v2 of their API, all was good but now all is dead when I try to connect.  This is where it fails in the account controller.

```
DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
```

Result always returns false, so never continues.

I have found a few examples which inherit IAuthenticationClient and allow you to setup additional scopes etc, and these expose the endpoints that facbook uses. I tried to update these urls to use the new API (v2.3) but still the same error.

Has anyone encountered this and what steps did you do to resolve this?